# Inserir dados com pymysql em um banco de dados mysql error. Como resolver?

Tags: mysql, python, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

seqteste.txt or List:

```
>gb:KX262887|Organism:Zika virus|Strain Name:103451|Segment:null|Subtype:Asian|Host:Human
GTTGTTGATCTGTGTGAATCAGACTGCGACAGTTCGAGTTTGAAGCGAAAGCTAGCAACAGTATCAACAG
GTTTTATTTTGGATTTGGAAACGAGAGTTTCTGGTCATGAAAAACCCAAAAAAGAAATCCGGAGGATTCC

>gb:KX262887|Organism:Zika virus|Strain Name:103451|Segment:null|Subtype:Asian|Host:Human
    GTTGTTGATCTGTGTGAATCAGACTGCGACAGTTCGAGTTTGAAGCGAAAGCTAGCAACAGTATCAACAG
    GTTTTATTTTGGATTTGGAAACGAGAGTTTCTGGTCATGAAAAACCCAAAAAAGAAATCCGGAGGATTCC

>gb:KX262887|Organism:Zika virus|Strain Name:103451|Segment:null|Subtype:Asian|Host:Human
    GTTGTTGATCTGTGTGAATCAGACTGCGACAGTTCGAGTTTGAAGCGAAAGCTAGCAACAGTATCAACAG
    GTTTTATTTTGGATTTGGAAACGAGAGTTTCTGGTCATGAAAAACCCAAAAAAGAAATCCGGAGGATTCC
```

mysqldb:

```
id   id_name host  organism  seq
```

script/ code:

```
import pymysql.cursors
import pymysql as MySQLdb
import pymysql
from Bio import SeqIO

try:
    conexao = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="",db="db_teste")
    print("conectado")
    print(conexao)
except:
    print("Não conectado")



for item in SeqIO.parse('seqteste.txt', 'fasta'):
    dados = print('>{}\t{}'.format(str(item.description).replace('|', '\t'), item.seq),)
    with conexao:
         with conexao.cursor() as cursor:
            sql =  "INSERT INTO `tabelateste` (`id`, `id_name`, `host`, `organism`, `seq`) VALUES(3, %s, %s, %s,%s)"
            print(sql)
            cursor.execute(sql,(3,dados,dados,dados,dados))
            conexao.commit()
```

error:

```
INSERT INTO `tabelateste` (`id`, `id_name`, `host`, `organism`, `seq`) VALUES(3, %s, %s, %s,%s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\B\Desktop\codeinserir.py", line 21, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql,(3,dados,dados,dados,dados))
  File "C:\Users\B\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 146, in execute
    query = self.mogrify(query, args)
  File "C:\Users\B\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 125, in mogrify
    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

code2  :

```
for linha in alllines:
    seqt = linha.replace("|","\t")
    seqin =  SeqIO.parse(seqt, "fasta")
    for i in seqin:
     print(i.id,i.seq)
     with con:
         with con.cursor() as cursor:
            sql = "INSERT INTO `tabelateste` (`id_name`,`seq`) VALUES (%s, %s)"
            cursor.execute(sql,(i.id , i.seq))
            con.commit()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\B\Desktop\codeinserir.py", line 25, in <module>
    DEanalysisfile = open (argumentos.file, 'r')
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

saída esperada:

mysqldb

```
 id  id_name            host        organism         seq
 1   gb:KX262887        Human       Zika Virus       aatgtgttt
```

Estou tentando inserir dados de um arquivo seqteste.txt num banco de dados mysql mas o resultado é sempre null. Como resolver esse problema? O que estou fazendo de errado??

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Usando o primeiro exemplo, testa tirando o 3 do tuple, ficar só assim `cursor.execute(sql,(dados,dados,dados,dados))`, porque o "3" já está harcoded na query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confesso que fiquei com algumas dúvidas:

- Por que importar o pymysql com o nome de MySQLdb sendo que você poderia instalar o MySQLdb diretamente?
- Porque importar duas vezes o pymysql?
- Por que inserir os dados como na pergunta:  `cursor.execute(sql,(3,dados,dados,dados,dados))`? Isso funcionou alguma vez?

Pra fazer a inserção de dados no banco, vc precisa passar chave e valor, ou seja, os nomes das colunas conforme no banco de dados e os valores que serão colocados lá. Como o Python identificaria que dado colocar se o valor é '*dados*' ?

A sua **conexao** não retornava nada, e isso funcionou alguma vez?

Saber essas coisas é uma curiosidade mesmo, porque não aparenta que você seja totalmente leiga no que está fazendo e acredito que possa dividir com a gente o que sabe.

Segue o código.

```
import pymysql as MySQLdb
from Bio import SeqIO


def conexao():
    try:
        conn = MySQLdb.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            passwd="",
            db="db_teste"
        )
        print("conectado")
        return conn
    except MySQLdb.Error as e:
        print(f'Erro ao conectar no Servidor MySQL: {e}')


def desconectar(conn):
    if conn:
        conn.close()


for item in SeqIO.parse('seqteste.txt', 'fasta'):
    dado = item.description.replace('|', '\n').splitlines()
    resumo = []

    for i in dado:
        d = i.replace(':', '\n').splitlines()
        resumo.append(d[1])

    id_name = resumo[0]
    organism = resumo[1]
    host = resumo[5]
    seq = item.seq
    conn = conexao()
    try:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO tabelateste (id_name, host, organism, seq) "
                       f"VALUES('{id_name}', '{host}', '{organism}', '{seq}');"
                       )
        conn.commit()

        print(f"INSERT INTO tabelateste (id_name, host, organism, seq) "
              f"VALUES('{id_name}', '{host}', '{organism}', '{seq}');")
    except MySQLdb.Error as e:
        print(f'Erro ao conectar no Servidor MySQL: {e}')
    
    desconectar(conn)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por que importar o pymysql com o nome de MySQLdb sendo que você poderia instalar o MySQLdb diretamente?

Muito Obrigada! Sou iniciante... Por que importar duas vezes o pymysql? Vi em um tutorial...; Por que inserir os dados como na pergunta:  cursor.execute(sql,(3,dados,dados,dados,dados))? Isso funcionou alguma vez? Funcionou... Mas os dados foram inseridos como Null... Não consegui instalar o Mysqldb.... Ocorreu um erro ao rodar o código sugerido...

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\B\Desktop\teste2.py", line 30, in <module>
    resumo.append(d[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: existe uma possibilidade disso ter acontecido porque vc estava tentando inserir um ```print``` no banco de dados... o print retorna null quando vc tenta armazenar numa variável.

Comment: insira na linha 29 ```print(dado)``` o resultado é isso: ['gb:KX262887', 'Organism:Zika virus', 'Strain Name:103451', 'Segment:null', 'Subtype:Asian', 'Host:Human']

Comment: Obrigada! Consegui resolver... Porque sou iniciante e você me ajudou muito! Valeu mesmo! ;) @CarlosCortez

Comment: funcionou mesmo? eu já ia ver o erro q vc postou aqui...

Comment: Sim. Foi um ajuste no tipo de dado ou tamanho que estava errado no meu...Mas já consertei ...

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite Lara, acredito que esteja instalado o pymysql então poderia ser o tipo lá no banco de dados, você pode tá enviando uma string e o banco esperando um inteiro, vale a pena verificar e manda o print aqui.

Comment: Coloquei o erro no post ou editei